# Define network architecture manually using connection profile in Hyperledger Composer

Tags: hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I am trying to manually define the componenets of my network i.e. 2 orderers and 2 peers. The default structure created by ./createComposerProfile.sh as demonstrated [here](http://www.goverticalworkshop.com/resources/setup-fabric-and-composer-page) has only 1 orderer and 1 peer.

I have tried editing the file at ~/.composer-connection-profiles/hlfv1/connection.json to no avail. It simply ignores my edits and still creates the default network.

How do I go about doing this?

Answer (score 0):

the connection profile represents how you want to interact with a hyperledger fabric network, it doesn't define the network. Hyperledger composer is designed to work with whatever Hyperledger fabric network you define, you then need to create connection profiles that represent that defined network. 
If you want a 2 peer network, you need to create one yourself then build a connection profile that represents how you want to interact with that network.
See http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/build_network.html
for information about how to build fabric networks.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification david_k. However, I would like to know how to change the configuration of the network that the .composer.sh file, which is used to start the composer playground locally (including setting and starting up the Hyperledger network), uses.

Comment: The single line installer is there to get users up and running with Composer. What you want to do is beyond the intention of that. We provide a simple development fabric for people to try working with a real fabric. To composer it shouldn't matter what fabric is being used as the connection profiles are defined correctly for that fabric (and you import the correct admin identities etc). Our fabric dev server is not there as an example on building a fabric network or as a starting point to be extended.

Comment: Details on how on connection profiles can be found here
https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/reference/connectionprofile.html
but unfortunately we don't much around what identities you need to import for composer to be able to install and start a business network.

Comment: So after creating a connection profile for a sample network provided by the fabric samples. How do I go about linking the connection profile with my network such that it runs locally and I can access the network on my local playground?

Answer (score 0):

in answer to *'How do I go about linking the connection profile with my network'* and referring back to your original problem - you need to 1) create a separate subdirectory under .composer-connection-profiles - you tried editing the connection.json in the `hlfv1` subdirectory I suspect and that was recreated. You need to create your own subdirectory first (at the same level, same permissions as 'hlfv1' profile from the Dev setup) and call it (say) *hlfv1custom*. Then add your connection.json file there. As you're setting up 'local' - you can probably use the existing connection.json as the basis for your custom one (adding the info about your new Fabric setup eg additional peer(s) etc into the new connection.json (its `"type"` (in the conx profile) is still 'hlfv1' fyi) - . See more info here and an example of a HLFV1 connection.json -> https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/reference/connectionprofile.html

Comment: Hi Paul, the link is taking me back to this page. Kindly check on it. And yes, I discovered the recreation you talked about above. Thanks

Comment: hi Goodman, thanks, I put in the correct link (edited the answer above). You're welcome.